# import package in android studio

Tags: java, google-maps, android-studio, import

I am trying to import these packages

```
 import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
 import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
```

but is gives me error that it cannot find them

Comment: What does your `app.gradle` look like?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put space in below line after import keyword.

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
```